# Python, Error audio Recording in 16000Hz using Pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I use Python 2.7.3, Mac OS 10.8.2 and Xcode 4.5.1

I am trying to record sound using PyAudio following the instructions in http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

and using the program

```
"""PyAudio example: Record a few seconds of audio and save to a WAVE file."""

import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
   data = stream.read(CHUNK)
   frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

It works well with `RATE = 44100`. But I want to record with `RATE = 16000` and `CHANNELS = 1`

Changing the values give me an error as[image]

How will  I be able to record with `RATE = 16000`?

Comment: Does upping the chunk size (e.g. to 4096) solve the problem?

Comment: @nneonneo: No it does not. Only works perfectly with 44100

Comment: Hm. I've run into this issue before, but never solved it. It might be a bug in PortAudio, or an unsupported recording configuration. You might be able to use a sample rate conversion library if you want 16000 Hz output.

Comment: You can use e.g. [pylibsamplerate](http://code.google.com/p/pyzic/wiki/PyLibSampleRate) (requires Numpy), which has a very simple API to do conversion (simply `src_simple(a, 16000/44100.)` once you have your audio converted to a Numpy array, as `np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)`). But, this is still a bit more complicated than I suspect you want, so I hope someone can provide a good answer to this question soon.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [How do I get a list of my device's audio sample rates using PyAudio or PortAudio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623572/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-my-devices-audio-sample-rates-using-pyaudio-or-portaudio). Your device probably doesn't support 16000 as a sampling rate and as already suggested you'll have to downsample it from 44100. The `audiospeex` codec in pyaudio seems to support resampling.

Comment: I am having the same error, but at 44100. Mac OSX Python 2.6. Same code (from PyAudio examples). I clicked on the link above ('How do I get a list of ...') and it is okay with 44100. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem.  The issue was fixed in portaudio, but brew installed an old version for me.   I upgraded with

```
brew install portaudio --HEAD
```

and then was able to run your code with CHANNELS=1 and RATE=16000