# PyAudio ErrNo Input Overflowed -9981

Tags: python, pyaudio

I was getting the same error as the user in

[Python, Error audio Recording in 16000Hz using Pyaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994981/python-error-audio-recording-in-16000hz-using-pyaudio)

The error was the same (except for the line numbers) as in the below graphic:

[image: this link]

As I was writing this, I found the solution to my problem in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733903/pyaudio-input-overflowed). The solution was to up the bitrate to 48000. But I had already "been approved" at 44100

```
if p.is_format_supported(44100.0,  # Sample rate
    input_device=devinfo["index"],
    input_channels=devinfo['maxInputChannels'],
    input_format=pyaudio.paInt16):
print 'Yay!'
```

Does anyone know why I was approved at 44100 and was overflowing but it works fine at 48000? (I was also approved for 48000).

Ordinarily I am the type of guy to get the solution and move on, but this time, I feel that I need to know. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that the device actually support 44.1. Even though the device states  it does support it, it's not always actually supporting it.