# google cloud speech api audio data is being streamed too slow

Tags: speech-recognition, audio-recording, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm using below method to convert speech to text using microphone, and the sample rate is 16000. I have tested it on Windows 10 machine initially and it worked fine and later when I tested the same script on Windows 7 machine it is not working properly and I'm getting the below error message.

```
audio data is being streamed too slow. please stream audio data approximately at real time
```

How to decide which sample rate to beused on which machine? What could be the problem with my Windows 7 machine?

```
// [START speech_streaming_mic_recognize]
static async Task StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
{
  // code here....
  StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
  {
    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
    {
      Encoding =
        RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
      SampleRate = 16000,
    },
    InterimResults = false,
  }
  // code here........
}
```

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: You might be able to specify the sample rate when you open the audio stream (I have no idea how to do that on windows though).  Alternatively, you can try to figure out the default sample rate.  If you can use Python you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623572/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-my-devices-audio-sample-rates-using-pyaudio-or-portaudio

Comment: I found sample rate 16000 is suggested in many forums/blogs. And we had experienced the issue when the network bandwidth was low(slow internet) so may be the problem depends on the internet connection not on the system.

Comment: Ahh that's interesting.  In that case, I guess you could try saving the audio and then using the synchronous API to recognize it after you've saved the entire audio segment.  I doubt that API cares how fast you send the audio.

Comment: as per the project requirement, we need to populate a textbox simultaneously as user is speaking using his/her microphone.

Comment: In that case, I think your best bet is to contact Google and request that they adjust the slowness threshold for your account (they can often change such things).  Alternatively, you could try using another audio encoding or a lower sample rate to reduce the bandwidth.